# Can Intellisense recognize javascript prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, prototype, intellisense, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and I would like Intellisense to recognize javascript prototype functions.  Is there a way to configure it to do so?

```
function MyObject() {}

MyObject.prototype.foo = function() {};
MyObject.prototype.bar = function() {};

var myObj = new MyObject();

myObj.  //I want Intellisense to show me the foo and bar functions here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is supported in the latest versions of VS Code.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Salsa

Comment: I can confirm you get the intellisense OP was after out of the box now.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when i export the file and require in another file in nodejs but it works on same file in my current version. Any way to make it work?